# What's so special about this pdf page?

Tags: linux, browser, pdf, okular

I'm in Linux, Kubuntu 22.10.

Some programs, including the Plasma PDF viewer Okular, display blank some of the pages in a specific (1000+ pages) pdf, but other programs, including some internet browsers, display all pages without blanks.

After extracting all pages as pdf, the same happens for the same problematic pages.

Testing with other programs and summing up:

- all pages are seen by WPS PDF, Master PDF, Firefox, Vivaldi browser, Opera (therefore I guess also Chromium/Chrome), LibreOffice Draw, ImageMagick, mupdf, PDF Studio Viewer
- blanks (with just a footer) are displayed in Okular, Qpdfviewer, PDF Aranger, Falkon (internet browser!), Inskape, Krita
- Evince (Document Viewer) installed as snap in Kubuntu cannot open the large file, nor any of the separate pdf pages, but gives an error: `Error opening file the.pdf: Permission denied` (it opens other pdf files)

([Here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1442495/925128) is my askubuntu question with more details.)

I have uploaded one of this tricky pdf pages on [DocDroid](https://docdro.id/ib8e3zz) for testing.

How could I find more details on such files?

(I'm curious about what's at work here - although for practical purposes I can fix this by printing to pdf in a browser or by simply just using a different pdf viewer).

Please download the page and see if you could give some details for why this page may be different by contrast to [this](https://docdro.id/kgIl45I) one (which is the same but fixed by printed to pdf 'as image' in Opera).

Comment: The vector graphics on the broken pages could be overly complex and/or subtly erroneous.

Comment: Not necessarily! I find that 3rd party PDF readers often struggle with public transport network maps: super slow rendering, lagging interaction. Meanwhile, Adobe Reader has no problems with these whatsoever. PDF readers are not born equal, unfortunately.

Comment: @DanielB - So Adobe Reader has no problems with this. I have posted here because I thought this might be a general pdf-specific issue, and that some Windows tool might read and report what the problem is. But the issue seems not even Linux, but KDE-specific, namely limited to Okular and other tools based on `poppler`. I'll keep this Q here a bit more, then move or re-post on Unix&Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Analysis process**

I downloaded the page and discovered a strange fact :
Both Adobe Reader and Foxit Reader can display the text,
but it's impossible to copy it correctly.
Any other application would display the pasted text with
distortions.

I thought this was a matter of font, so I used Adobe Reader to see the
embedded fonts, and discovered two fonts that were missing on my
computer : TimesNewRomanPSMT and ArialMT.
But downloading the fonts changed nothing - other applications
didn't still manage to paste the copied text as it was.

I then tried a sample of the text on the page with the
[WhatTheFont website](https://www.myfonts.com/pages/whatthefont),
but it failed to identify the font from among its 130,000 fonts.

An example of the problems in copy-paste
of the text is when I copy this original text:

[image]

But I get this when pasting in the browser or in Word,
which is just a non-exact approximation:

> Oral si suflet, revista Institutului de Filologie si folklor publIcata de Ovid Densuseanu, Bucuresti de la 1929.

Notice the character errors in the pasted text.

When I open the PDF with Word, I get a page which is just
an image of the ancient text, and I cannot select any text in it.

**Conclusion**

This PDF behaves as if the displayed part was a background image
of an ancient text using a some old font, with a foreground text
that was created using an imprecise OCR.

The OCR'ed text behaves as if it is the text in the image,
as it is transparent and placed *in front of the image*.
It's selectable and its selection color is only partly transparent,
so it seems that you are selecting the displayed text, but you're
selecting instead the OCR'ed text.

An image viewer that doesn't correctly handle transparency
will show a blank page with the image not "showing through".
This is a transparency problem.

Comment: What does it mean exactly `cannot copy`? - Opening one of those files in a browser like Opera, the text can be copied/pasted rather well. Limitations can appear due to the quality of scanned old pages. I couldn't find other viewer that is unable to handle those files beside the Plasma/KDE-centered Okular, qpdfview and Falkon browser. As said in a comment under linked question, Okular uses `poppler`, the limitation might be coming from that.

Comment: I added more information about what I found, with another conjecture that seems to me to better explain what is happening.

Comment: What you see as a problem (`just an image of the ancient text`) is in fact just the way some pdf files are: instead of text (e.g.doc, docx) saved/printed as pdf they are made of photo images of book pages. That is nothing wrong with that (it's like any pdf with pictures). The fact that you cannot copy correctly is because of the quality of image (it's images of letters) and the OCR it's not perferct, so G is seem as O. But OCR can be applied, selection and even search may work under these limits.

Comment: Last link in question is to a page from the same big pdf, but one that seems ok: I think the problems you mentioned are present there too, so they are not what I'm talking about here. Thank you for your effort, but I guess in Windows you won't notice the difference between the two pages. I have posted here because I thought it might be a more general problem than just Linux/KDE, but I was wrong I guess: I should move this to the Linux-stackexchange.  See [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1359605/925128) a post on the two types of pdf = the difference is expected.

Comment: I have many many books just like what you describe as the problem here: scanned old books where pdf pages are pictures of book pages.  See [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8o4q2dj1hbxmekn/An_Account_of_the_Principalities_of_Wall.pdf?dl=0) one (it's open edition) They are just fine, OCR recognition, selection and search work, although not as perfect as in a digital-text-based pdf. See the difference at the askubuntu link in previous comment.

Comment: For an OCR'ed text to behave as if it was the the text in the image, the text must be selectable and transparent and placed *in front of the image*. An image viewer that doesn't correctly handle transparency will show a blank page with the image not "showing through". I think that this answers your question.

Comment: Yes. `An image viewer that doesn't correctly handle transparency will show a blank page with the image not "showing through"` seems the answer - in previous comment. (But is that what you say in the answer above?) -- The cause of this might be a bug with the `poppler` tool - I have posted a bug report [here](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=462304)

Comment: As a solution, in order to use my preferred pdf viewer (which has other advantages like full dark mode etc) I have fixed the big pdf by printing it as pdf in Firefox (in batches of ca 200-250 pages, considering my 4 GB of RAM limit). Then, I've joined the resulting "printed" output.

Comment: I have clarified my answer. I think that "What's so special about this pdf page" has been fully answered.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think that only the part taken from your last comment is the answer ("full" answer so to speak). The rest, the initial and longer parts about fonts and pasting in Word describe aspects which may be problematic in a sense (`just an image of the ancient text`), but which is simply not my problem. As I said, I have many such pdfs that all my programs can handle fine. Text-as-image is not the issue. It is *some* such pages that are the problem. These are indeed odd, and you have possibly come close to describing why in the comment added to answer. See bug report for technicalities.

Comment: I detailed in the beginning the exploring process which led me to the final answer. All the information is now in the answer, not any more partly in the comments. But if you don't wish to accept this answer, it's your choice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140897/discussion-between-cipricus-and-harrymc).

Comment: I see your answer as being this: **the problem is one of transparency, and transparency varies in the different pages in a way that cannot be handled well by some viewers.** I'll mark it as definitive, but I think it will gain by losing the preliminary part and especially by describing in layman's terms what's that transparency.

Comment: The preliminary part is what took me the most time, and I believe it's required to show the validity of the conclusion. Thank you for accepting.

Answer (score 0):

As a complementary information:

- This is a bug with `poppler`, posted [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/-/issues/1319), initially [here](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=462304), Evince and Atril (Mint PDF viewer) are also affected.
- To fix the pages I have printed them "as pdf" in Firefox (or Chrome, Vivaldi, Opera - with these 'print as image' must be selected too). Depending on RAM capacity, one shouldn't "print to pdf" more than 200-300 pages at once in order to avoid freezes/crashes.